# How to draw a Curve onto a mesh with the Draw tool

Tags: snapping, curve-modifier

I can create a Curve line, then move it over to my mesh, turn on the "snap to faces" then move it point by point to my mesh (snapping them onto the surfce as I go) and generate paths on the surface of my mesh in that way.

But, is it possuble to draw onto a mesh with the Curve Pen or Draw tool and have the Curve snap to mesh's faces.

I am looking for a faster way to create hair curve paths (not the built in particle method).

Answer (score 2):

Add *Curve* object, switch to *Edit* mode *Delete* curve, take **Draw** tool (free-hand pen), under Tool properties (N) switch to **Surface** ... draw a shape over your model ...

[image]

Notes:

- just be sure *Curve* object is set to **3D type**

Comment: Thanks, I saw this one already, I tried it and...

!) should I dd the curve to the object?
2) if I just add a curve - Delete it - Take the draw tool - change to surface and draw --- it just draws in 2D behind the object...

Any other thoughts?

Comment: If you checked my note bellow my screen ...share your blend to let us see.

Comment: Thanks - I did also check that 3D type was selected.... As for sharing a file, I was simply trying to do this in a blank statup scene on an added mesh-uv sphere

Comment: I just ran through the steps again - and it did work! Thanks for all your help