Draw curves on image reference's surface while in perspective view
When I add image ref (add/image/reference) , How can I draw curve (using curve pen) on the surface of this image reference while looking from perspective or camera view ?

If you add a reference image you aren't actually creating an object which you can draw onto. Use Add > Images > Images as Planes instead. (In Blender 4.2, it's the Add > Image > Mesh Plane menu entry.)

I tried the mesh plane, but when I draw a curve even with snap is ON, the curve won't be at the surface. what's wrong ?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291923/how-to-draw-a-curve-onto-a-mesh-with-the-draw-tool

@JohnEason I'm drawing using 'curve pen' tool. that draw on surface option only available on 'draw' tool. Is it possible using 'curve pen' and drawing on surface ?

Why do you want to use the Curve Pen tool? Use the Draw tool which has the Surface setting both on the top-left toolbar and the N panel.

@JohnEason it's a bug on 4.2 (osx m1 version). It doesn't work using Draw tool. but works on 3.4. But anyway, I prefer using Curve Pen -easier to setup the control points - rather than using freehand style.

The Draw tool using Surface works fine here in 4.2 under Windows. As said before, the Curve Pen tool doesn't have that option available unfortunately.
